# HTML. Как правильно оформлять class=" " id=" "

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Читал, что `class` и `id` правильно писать так: `color-picker selected-color`, неправильно вот так `color_picker selected_color`.

Но когда пишу на js довольно удобно пользоваться записями без тире

```
color_picker.style.display = ""
```

Недавно увидел что пишут еще таким способом:

```
class="colorPicker" id="selectedColor"
```

На сколько это правильно? И вообще что нужно использовать?

Очень благодарен понятные за ответы, особенно с объяснениями.

Comment: Холивар на эту тему не утихнет даже в пекле ядерной войны

Comment: О соглашениях - http://thecodelesscode.com/case/94?lang=ru

Comment: Ссылка по теме: https://habrahabr.ru/post/256109/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как именовать обычно зависит от предпочтений программиста или от того как принято в команде, но главное чтобы в проекте все было одинаково, а не так что в каждом месте по разному.

Посмотрите методологию именования в БЭМ
https://ru.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/

В целом про стиль программирования на js
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Answer (score 2):

Советую почитать вам о [БЭМ структуре](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/filestructure/), которую в последнее время многие используют.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно - это так, как разрешает спецификация. Спецификация никак не регламентирует **как** должны составляться имена классов и идентификаторов, устанавливая только допустимые символы.

Таким образом - *правильны* **все** варианты.

Какой именно подход использовать и для чего, каждый определяет сам.
Выбор может так же обуславливаться правилами принятыми в конкретной группе.

Comment: Вы возьмете меня к себе если я буду писать так - `Ka__-_-_koЙ---tО-seЛе--___----_Ktoр`? Или Вы хотите сказать что какая-то команда может заставить Вас писать так? Да нужно быть последним человеком на планете земля чтобы согласится так писать или сказать что так правильно.....

Comment: @OlmerDale, я бы посмотрел на человека, который может писать много кода с  такими селекторами. Возможно это нераскрытый талант энергию которого можно направить в мирных целях =D

Comment: @OlmerDale `Вы возьмете меня к себе если я буду писать так` - если в команде в компании принято писать так, то да - возьмут)) А также  если вы идете в компанию, в которой приняты какие-то свои правила оформления кода, которые вам совершенно не нравятся, то вы вполне можете уволиться и идти в другую. Но, как бы то ни было, раз символы позволительны, то можно писать всё что душе угодно, и организовывать свои правила именования селекторов. Законом не запрещено.

Comment: _Да нужно быть последним человеком на планете земля чтобы согласится так писать или сказать что так правильно_ - а есть какие-то аргументы того, что это _неправильно_?